# Seeding fails validation for nested tables (validates_presence_of)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

An Organization model has a 1:many association with a User model.
I have the following validation in my User model file:

```
belongs_to :organization
validates_presence_of :organization_id, :unless => 'usertype==1'
```

If usertype is 1, it means the user will have no organization associated to it. For a different usertype the presence of an organization_id should be mandatory.

The organization model includes:

```
has_many :users
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
```

My seeds file uses nesting and includes:

```
Organization.create!(name: "Fictious business",
                     address: Faker::Address.street_address,
                     city: Faker::Address.city,
  users_attributes: [email: "helpst@example.com",
                     username: "helpyzghtst", 
                     usertype: 2,
                     password: "foobar", 
                     password_confirmation: "foobar"])
```

On seeding this generates the error below. Removing the validation from the model solves it, but I don't want to do that. How can I solve this?

> Validation failed: Users organization can't be blank

Comment: Since usertype is 2, don't you need an organization_id in your users_attribute? Is changing the usertype to 1 in your seeds changing anything?

Comment: This has to do with nested attributes. Because users_attributes is nested, Rails automatically assigns the `organization_id` for that user. So no, I shouldn't need to specify the `organization_id`. This is confirmed when I remove the validation: the user is saves including its `organization_id`.

Comment: Right, I didn't put enough thought into it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Associated models and a nested form with validation not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31014077/associated-models-and-a-nested-form-with-validation-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this : [Validating nested association in Rails](http://homeonrails.com/2012/10/validating-nested-associations-in-rails/) (last chapter)

```
class User
  belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :users
  validates_presence_of :organization_id, :unless => 'usertype==1'
end

class Organization
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

The documentation is not quite clear about it but I think it's worth a try. see this [comment](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to#974-Undocumented-inverse-of-option), stating that the association lookout will use the objects in memory and not fetch them from the database, which would be what you need.

## EDIT

removed inverse_of on the Organization class.

Comment: I added `inverse_of` to the user model (not to the organization model, which as I understand is indeed correct; got an error message if I added to both models). Now it indeed seeded without error! Not completely sure I understand what it does and what you mean with "will use the objects in memory and not fetch them from the database". But it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
organization = Organization.create! name: "Fictious business",
                                    address: Faker::Address.street_address,
                                    city: Faker::Address.city

User.create! email: "helpst@example.com",
             username: "helpyzghtst", 
             usertype: 2,
             password: "foobar", 
             password_confirmation: "foobar"
             organization: organization
```

### UPDATE

When calling `Organization.create!` with nested attributes, rails first creates the `Organization` without any validations, then it **builds** the `User`, performs all validations on it, then saves it to database if all is green, just as calling `create` without the bang.

Comment: Although this would of course solve it, I would prefer to understand what is going on here. Also, since there might be something going on that might also in other situations besides seeding perhaps cause problems. I feel like my code should work.