# Associated models and a nested form with validation not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

**Update2:** I've cleaned up the code, which seems to have solved some of the problems. I've posted the new code as a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31072646/4499505).

**Update:** Organization and User have a 1:many relationship. My question concerns a joined signup form where both an organization and user are required. After maxcal's help on the original post, I've written a new `create` method for my nested form ("organization has many users"), as shown below. Also I added [`begin...rescue...end`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordInvalid.html) to the `create` method. The situation/problem now:

- Submitted with all valid info it works correctly.
- Submitted with invalid info for organization (doesn't matter if user is also invalid or not), it renders the page with the error messages, as we want it to, but it only shows errors for the organization details. Also, for the user details it has then emptied all the fields, which it shouldn't.
- Submitted with invalid info only for user, it renders the form again but without any error messages and all fields for user have been emptied.

Anyone got an idea what is wrong with the code? The problem seems to be more with the nested user than with organization (the parent). Also, `users_attributes.empty?` doesn't work, since an empty submitted form still includes such attributes, according to the log:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "organization"=>{"name"=>"", "bag"=>"", "users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"", "username"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "usertype"=>"2", "admin"=>"true"}}}, "commit"=>"Register"}
```

.

```
  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(new_params.except(:users_attributes))
begin
    if users_attributes.empty?
        @organisation.errors.add(:users, 'No user provided')
    end
    @organization.transaction do
      @organization.save!
      if users_attributes.any?
        @organization.users.create!(users_attributes)
      end
    end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => invalid
    if @organization.persisted?
      if @organization.users.any?
        @organization.users.each do |single_user|
          single_user.send_activation_email
        end
      end
      flash[:success] = "Confirmation email sent."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @organization.users.build if @organization.users.blank? 
      render :new
    end
end
  end

private
  # converts the hash of nested attributes hashes to an array
  def users_attributes
     new_params[:users_attributes].values
  end
end
```

---

---

**Original question:** 
I have two associated models and a nested form with validation. Unfortunately, it’s not working. 1) On *seeding* it generates the error `Validation failed: Users organization can't be blank`. I [previously posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30993850/seeding-fails-validation-for-nested-tables-validates-presence-of) a question about this and prematurely concluded it had solved it. It hasn’t. 2) Submitting my nested *signup form* with all fields filled in correctly, produces the flash error message `The form contains 1 error. Users organization can't be blank`.

How should I adjust my code to solve these issues?

Model files:

```
#User model
belongs_to :organization, inverse_of: :users
validates_presence_of :organization_id, :unless => 'usertype == 1'

# Organization model
has_many :users, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :users, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

validate  :check_user
private
  def check_user
    if users.empty?
      errors.add(:base, 'User not present')
    end
  end
```

Organization Controller methods

```
  def new
    @organization = Organization.new
    @user = @organization.users.build
  end

  def create
    @organization = Organization.new(new_params)
    if @organization.save
      @organization.users.each do |single_user|
        single_user.send_activation_email                 # Method in user model file.
      end
      flash[:success] = "Confirmation email sent."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      @organization.users.build if @organization.users.blank?
      render 'new'
    end
  end

def new_params
  params.require(:organization).permit(:name, :bag,
             users_attributes: [:email, :username, :usertype, :password, :password_confirmation])
end
```

The form:

```
  <%= form_for @organization, url: organizations_path do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :bag %>
    <%= f.fields_for :users do |p| %>
      <%= p.email_field :email %>
      <%= p.text_field :username %>
      <%= p.text_field :fullname %>
      <%= p.password_field :password %>
      <%= p.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      <%= p.hidden_field :usertype, value: 2 %>
    <% end %>
```

In my Seeds file I have:

```
Organization.create!(name: "Fictious business",
                     address: Faker::Address.street_address,
                     city: Faker::Address.city,
  users_attributes: [email: "helpst@example.com",
                     username: "helpyzghtst", 
                     usertype: 2,
                     password: "foobar", 
                     password_confirmation: "foobar"])
```

The log on the error on submitting the signup form:

```
Started POST "/organizations" 
Processing by OrganizationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0cR***Nnx4iReMiePg==", "organization"=>{"name"=>"test21", "bag"=>"tes21", "users_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"email"=>"test21@example.com", "username"=>"test21", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "usertype"=>"2"}}}, "commit"=>"Register"}
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (1.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test21@example.com') LIMIT 1
   (0.7ms)  SELECT "users"."email" FROM "users"  ORDER BY "users"."username" ASC
  User Exists (0.3ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER(users"."username") = LOWER('test21') LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."name") = LOWER('test21') LIMIT 1
  Organization Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "organizations" WHERE LOWER("organizations"."bag") = LOWER('tes21') LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Comment: try changing to `validates_presence_of :organization, :unless => 'usertype == 1'` (removing `_id`). i had a similar issue a while back that was fixed by this change

Comment: Tried it but unfortunately it generated the exact same errors.

Comment: mm. i checked my code and the only other difference is that inverse_of is on the organization model, not the user model

Comment: Use a lambda for unless. `unless: -> { usertype == 1 }`

Comment: If I change `:unless => 'usertype == 1'` to `:if=> 'usertype == 3'` (which is never), it works. That's because it then doesn't do any validation as usertype is never 3. But is shows the 2nd half of the `validates_presence_of` line works correctly, and it applies validation when usertype is not 1. So `unless: -> { usertype == 1 }` still generated the same error.  
If I apply `inverse_of` on the organization model instead, I get the error `InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError`. But I could also leave `inverse_of` out of my model; it doesn't seem to do much.

Comment: I don't have all the details but I think you should consider using Organization -> `validates_associated :users, presence: true` instead. Of course this depends on your requirements.

Comment: `has_many :users, inverse_of: :organization, dependent: :destroy` gave you that error?

Comment: @PhilVarg: Yes, that gave error `InverseOfAssociationNotFoundError`. 
@ Maxcal: I wish that was true, because I tried and then there are no error messages. However, my requirements are that for an user of `usertype != 1` there should be an organization associated with it. But an organization can also (temporarily) have no users.  Given the results, I think that validation is failing and not the syntax of the `validates_presence_of` line.

Comment: I have flagged your previous question as a duplicate since I am fairly certain that they have the same underlying issue and answer.

Comment: Handle the rollback manually instead of using `save!`. Use `save` in the `transaction` block, and `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` if `[@organization, @organization.users].map(&:errors).flatten.present?`

Comment: I replaced `save!` with `save` and as the last line within the `transaction` block, I added the `raise ActiveRecord::Rollback` line. Upon submitting the form with valid info, this generates the error: `undefined method 'errors' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` referring to "&:errors" in the `raise ...` line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your validation does not work due to a [Catch-22](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch-22_(logic))

> To apply for this job, you would have to be insane; but if you are
>   insane, you are unacceptable.

ActiveRecord models get their ID from the database when they are saved.
But the validation on the nested user runs before the organization is inserted into the the database.

You would guess that just checking `validates_presence_of` instead would pass:

```
validates_presence_of :organization, unless: -> { usertype == 1 }
```

Unfortunatly not. In order for `validates_presence_of :organization` to pass the organization must be persisted to the database. Catch-22 again.

In order for the validation to pass we would need to split creating the organization and user into two steps:

```
org = Organization.create(name: 'M & M Enterprises')
user = org.users.build(username: 'milo_minderbinder', ...)
user.valid?
```

Unfortunatly the means that you cannot use `accepts_nested_attributes_for :users` - well at least not straight off the bat.

By using a [transaction](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html) we can insert the organization into the the database and and roll back if the user is not valid.

```
def create
  @organization = Organization.new(new_params.except(:users_attributes))
  @organization.transaction do
    @organization.save!
    if new_params[:users_attributes].any?
      @organization.users.create!(new_params[:users_attributes])
    end
  end
  if @organization.persisted?
    # ...
    if @organization.users.any?
      # send emails ... 
    end
  else
    @organization.users.build if @organization.users.blank? 
    render :new
  end
end
```

### Followup questions

We use `@organization.persisted?` since we presumably want to redirect to the newly created organisation no matter if the there is a User record created.

> because the emails are sent to users? It shouldn't matter since organization is rolled back if no user is created.

The transaction is not rolled back if there is no user created. Only if the user(s) fails to save due to invalid parameters. This is based on your requirement:

> But an organization can also (temporarily) have no users.

If you need the @organisation to be invalid without users you could do:

```
  @organisation.errors.add(:users, 'No users provided') unless new_params[:users_attributes].any?
  @organization.transaction do
    @organization.save!
    if new_params[:users_attributes].any?
      @organization.users.create!(new_params[:users_attributes])
    end
  end
```

You would use `@organization.users.any?` to check if there are any users. `@organization.users.persisted?` will not work since `.persisted?` is a method on model instances - not collections.

> On a different note, I assume it's not possible to overwrite/update an existing organization/user with this method (which shouldn't be) instead of always creating a new record?

Right, since this will always issue two SQL insert statements it will not alter existing records.

It is up to you however to create validations that guarantee the uniqueness of the database columns (IE you don't want several records with the same user.email or organiation.name).

On the plus side is that none of these caveats apply when updating an existing organization:

```
def update
  @organisation.update(... params for org and and users ...)
end
```

Since you don't get the whole chicken or egg dilemma when validating the users.

Comment: Use `Organization.create!(...).users.create(...)` instead of nested attributes in your seed file.

Comment: I have another validation in the organization model that now generates an error on submitting the form. I've added the `check_user` validation to my original post. Should I remove this validation? But then again, shouldn't I also have a validation at the model level that makes it impossible to create a new organization without a user?

Comment: Thanks Maxcal, I'm trying to understand the code (great to learn about methods such as transaction and persisted). So I guess the part inside `.transaction` saves the organization and then creates the user, using different param sections. If either fails `.transaction` rolls back organization **as well as** user. *Am I right?* It should roll back both if either organization or user is invalid or not present at all.

Comment: Then we move on to the `@organization.persisted?` part where we will send the emails. Because of `. persisted?` it only does so if a new organization is created in the db. *Should we perhaps change this to `if @organization.users.persisted?` because the emails are sent to users?* It shouldn't matter since organization is rolled back if no user is created, but still... On a different note, *I assume it's not possible to overwrite/update an existing organization/user with this method (which shouldn't be) instead of always creating a new record?*

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The transaction will roll back if either fails .

Comment: Would you say it's safe to remove the `validate  :check_user` from the model file? Your code makes sure at the controller level there's a user and an organization. At the model level `validates_presence_of` ensures for users there's an organization. Lastly, `validate  :check_user` would ensure at model level that there's a user for an organization (only at the moment of the creation of a new organization).

Comment: I think you would need to get rid of `validate :check_user` since it leads to a circular argument (chicken or egg).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81437/discussion-between-maxcal-and-nick).

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but you can specify the inverse_of option to the association to make this work.